# Flutter and Firebase database, update to collection type

Tags: flutter

I want to update my collection document of Firebase about boolean type.

Under is my method.

```
  Future<void> MessageRead(String userId) async {
      var forRead = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chats').doc(userId).update({
        'isRead': true,
      });
    setState(() {
      forRead;
    });
  }
```

And here is my UI part.

```
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
            String userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
            MessageRead(userId);
          }
        },
        child: NavigationDestination(
          icon: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').where('isRead', isEqualTo: false).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Badge(
                  label: Text('?'),
                  child: Icon(Icons.messenger_sharp),
                );
              }
              var unreadMsgCount = snapshot.data!.docs.length;
              return Badge(
                label: Text(unreadMsgCount.toString()),
                child: Icon(Icons.messenger_sharp),
              );
            },
          ),
          label: 'Messages',
        ),
      ),
```

When I click NavigationDestination, boolean type of "chats" collection, (false) change to true.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?